# TFS: Inject/replace file content using TFS properties or variables (e. g. to inject the workspace path)

Tags: tfs

I want to replace the content of a configuration file that is
under version control with TFS every time I do a "get latest" or "checkout"
to inject the absolute workspace path.

Is there a feature to do this (e. g. a mechanism like CVS variables that were substituted)?

Comment: You can't use relative paths?

Comment: Unfortunately not because the utils I a want to access have a fixed absolute path while the projects may have a deliberately deep sub path so there is no stable relative path to "climb up the tree"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS doesn't have such feature by default. You need to write your own project or script to monitor the workspace and replace the configuration file once there are files updated.